# What's the updated version of Manual Recursion to polling using Observables?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, reactive-programming, rx-java, observable, rx-android

A little bit of context: 
In this link: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/448 @ben-lesh proposed a Manual Recursion implementation to polling using Observables.
However in latest RxJava version there is no `OnSubscribeFunc`.

Here it is my current implementation:

```
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Item>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Subscriber<? super Item> innerSubscriber) {

            Schedulers.io().createWorker()
                      .schedulePeriodically(new Action0() {
                          @Override
                          public void call() {
                              searchObservable()
                                      .doOnNext(new Action1<Item>() {
                                          @Override
                                          public void call(Item item) {
                                              innerSubscriber.onNext(item);
                                          }
                                      })
                                      .doOnError(new Action1<Throwable>() {
                                          @Override
                                          public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                                              if (throwable != null) {
                                                  innerSubscriber.onError(throwable);
                                              }
                                          }
                                      })
                                      .doOnCompleted(new Action0() {
                                          @Override
                                          public void call() {
                                              innerSubscriber.onCompleted();
                                          }
                                      }).subscribe(); // Set subscriber?
                          }
                      }, initialDelay, pollingInterval, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        }
    })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) // performs networking on background thread
            .observeOn(observeOnScheduler) // sends notifications to another Scheduler, usually the UI thread
            .subscribe(subscriber); // The subscriber
```

`searchObservable` performs a service request. This is working fine the first run, this is, the data is passed to the `subscriber`. However, after waiting the `pollingInterval`, the data returns and the `doOnNext` is executed but the data is not passed to the UI. Do I need to set any subscriber in the `Action` that `schedulePeriodically` takes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what is working fine for me and follows the paradigm of what Manual Recursion is:

```
public void manualRecursionPollingStrategy(Subscriber<Item> subscriber, Scheduler observeOnScheduler, long initialDelay, long pollingInterval) {
            Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Item>() {
                @Override
                public void call(final Subscriber<? super Item> innerSubscriber) {
                    Schedulers.newThread().createWorker()
                              .schedulePeriodically(new Action0() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void call() {
                                              searchByHashtagObservable()
                                                      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) // performs networking on background thread
                                                      .observeOn(observeOnScheduler) // sends notifications to a Scheduler, usually the
                                                              // UI thread
                                                      .subscribe(
                                                              new Action1<Item>() {
                                                                  @Override
                                                                  public void call(Item item) {
                                                                      subscriber.onNext(item);
                                                                  }
                                                              },
                                                              new Action1<Throwable>() {
                                                                  @Override
                                                                  public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                                                                      if (throwable != null) {
                                                                          subscriber.onError(throwable);
                                                                      }
                                                                  }
                                                              },
                                                              new Action0() {
                                                                  @Override
                                                                  public void call() {
                                                                      subscriber.onCompleted();
                                                                  }
                                                              }
                                                      )
                                  }
                              }, initialDelay, pollingInterval, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
                }
            })
              .observeOn(observeOnScheduler) // sends notifications to a Scheduler, usually the UI thread
              .subscribe(subscriber);
```

Please notice that I subscribe to `searchByHashtagObservable()` and call the `onNext`, `onError` and `onCompleted` of the `Subscriber` passed as param.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It stops because you are calling `innerSubscriber.onCompleted` which terminates the sequence on the first run. There are standard operators that can get you the same effect without the need to create a custom Observable:

```
Observable.interval(initialDelay, pollingInterval, TimeUnit.MINUTES, Schedulers.io())
.onBackpressureBuffer()
.concatMap(v -> searchObservable())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(subscriber);
```

(Remark: no need for subscribeOn() here because interval will emit on Schedulers.io() anyway.)